# Get actual dimensions of image uploaded with carrierwave using fastimage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave, minimagick

I am trying to get the dimensions of a image using carrierwave but I was hoping to get the dimensions with my own code I created trying to run fastimage `after_save` or `after commit`. I get this error:

```
wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
  Extracted source (around line #45): 
  # [String] contents of the file
  #
  def read
    file.read if file.respond_to?(:read)
  end

carrierwave (0.11.2) lib/carrierwave/uploader/proxy.rb:45:in `read'
fastimage (2.1.0) lib/fastimage.rb:343:in `block in fetch_using_read'
```

model would look something like this

```
class Micropost < ApplicationRecord

  after_save :change_picture_dimensions
  mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader

 def change_picture_dimensions
  if :picture?
    widthheight = FastImage.size(picture)
    if widthheight[0] >= 501
      newheightratio =  widthheight[1].to_f / widthheight[0].to_f
  newheight = newheightratio * 500
      self.picture = "<img src=\"" + picture.to_s + "\" width=\"500\" height=\"" +  newheight.to_s + "\">"
      else
      self.picture = "<img src=\"" + picture.to_s + "\" width=\"" + widthheight[0].to_s + "\" height=\"" + widthheight[1].to_s + "\">"
      end
    end
  end
```

This is just a local file on my system. I can get dimensions using minimagick [here](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3A-Get-image-dimensions) but wanted to know more about the process of carrierwave and why I cannot use my method to get the dimensions cause of this error? In my method I am just using a ratio to keep the aspect ratio but fit into the fixed width of a div I have for any image.

**EDIT**: I realised I need to do it before the object is saved but even with before_create I get the same error.

Comment: What is the variable `picture` in this case?

Comment: picture is a .jpg I have on my local file system coming in from my fields. the problem I am having is that Fastimage can get dimensions off of a url from another server and I am sure can get them off of a locallly stored file but I do not understand how to get them when its  on my local system ie I do not know how to access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot assign picture a string. It must be an URL, file or an IO object.

If you want to preprocess your image width to fit 500px just declare the following:

```
# app/uploaders/picture_uploader.rb
class PictureUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
   ...
   process resize_to_fit: [500, nil]
end

class Micropost < ApplicationRecord
  mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader
end
```

To save an image from another server you can do:

```
micropost = Micropost.create(
  picture: 'http://server.example.org/image.png'
)
```

and now you can render it on the page

```
= image_tag micropost.picture.url
```

You can also store image size in your model. Read [this documentation](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-Get-image-dimensions) how to do this. After you saved your image dimensions into a picture model, you can specify them in `image_tag`, but it will be redundant I think because browser will detect image size automatically

```
= image_tag micropost.picture.url, width: picture.width, height: picture.height
```

Comment: Ok that sound right. To clarify does carrierwave save the name of the file as a string (ofcourse) and points a reference to the file stored in public uploads folder? I just wanted to know that part so I understand what I am doing. I say it does but when you cant see whats going on its a little hard to tell. I couldnt find anything on it. Then as you said it creates a url for bringing pictures out...

Comment: Ok I am reading StringIO and it appears to wrap the source in a File object so it can read from the file. :D